# Flask-Restful RegParse conditional verification

Tags: python, flask-restful

Suppose there is a typical flask-restful resource:

```
 class Foo(Resource):
      def post(self):
      parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
      parser.add_argument('type', required=True, choices=('local', 'ftp'), type=str)
      ...
      args = parser.parse_args()
```

There is a `type`. Depending on this param value I need either to verify one group of parameters or another.

For now all parameters except `type` are optional. So I code I look at `type` and for each case manually verify if needed parameter exists or not:

```
 parser.add_argument('ip', required=False, ...)
 parser.add_argument('login', required=False, ...)
 ...
 if args['type'] == 'ftp':
      if not all(a in args for a in ('ip', 'login', 'password')):
           raise Exception('Missing some params')
 elif args['type'] == '...'
```

I want to avoid `if ... else` checks. Is it possible to construct `RegParser` in such way? If not then maybe I need to look at a different framework?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a way to do this using the built-in ReqParser. I manually check the conditional arguments. It would be great if someone else had a better idea, as I'd like to learn this too.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila it's maybe possible with cerberus. If maybe you used it in such a way you can post an answer with an example.